# Split line to create two variables

Tags: bash, awk, sed, trim

Is there a way to split this line on the last `_` to create two variables?

The folder in Linux is of the form `Project_Data1_xxx` or `Project_Data1_Sub1_xxx`. I would like to create two variables :

1. for the first two or three octets
2. for what comes after the last `_`.

I have spent quite a bit of time on this and apologize as I am new to Linux and I am not yet understanding all the differences between windows and linux.

**Question:** do I break it up into two statements to get the front and the back?

I am doing `ls -1` of a folder into a variable. So I do

```
#!/bin/bash
srcIn=/scripts/server1
dstIn=/scripts/server2
data=test

sourcein=$(ls $srcIn/ | grep $data)
destinationin=$(ls $dstIn/ | grep $data)
```

I then get:

```
echo $destinationin 
test_data1_xxx test_data2_xxx test_data3_xxx

echo $sourcein 
test_data1_ccc test_data2_ccc test_data3_ccc
```

In the end. I need to create a copy line that goes:

```
cp /test_data1_ccc/* /test_data1_xxx
cp /test_data2_ccc/* /test_data2_xxx
```

and so on... There may be 2 or 3 underscores but the format is always the same.

The strings `xxx` and `ccc` could be `abc123` or `ccc567` and do not necessarily have the same number of characters. The one thing that doesn't change is the only difference in the two locations is what follows the last `_` - but they will always be different.

Comment: Don't parse `ls` --> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 3):

I would do it in two steps. Assuming that the string is inside a variable:

```
name=Project_Data1_xxx
$ echo ${name%_*}
Project_Data1
$ echo ${name##*_}
xxx
```

- `${var%foo}` removes the shortest occurrence of `foo` from the end
- `${var##foo}` removes the longest occurrence of `foo` from the start

These [parameter expansions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02) can be combined with the wildcard `*` to remove anything, rather than a string literal.

In the context of your script, I would suggest something like this:

```
for input_dir in /scripts/server1/*data*/; do
    base=${input_dir%_*}                 # trim the last part
    base=${base##*/}                     # trim the leading part
    dest=( /scripts/server2/"$base"*/ )  # find the destination dir
    if [[ ${#dest[@]} -eq 1 ]]; then
        cp "$input_dir"* "${dest[0]}"
    else
        echo "${#dest[@]} destination paths found, expected 1"
    fi
done
```

Comment: it is so close: I changed *data* to test* because that is what I am searching on and I get:
   
cp: cannot stat '/scripts/server1/test_data1_ccc//*': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/scripts/server1/test_data2_ccc//*': No such file or directory
cp: cannot stat '/scripts/server1/test_data3_ccc//*': No

Comment: I removed the extra slash after `"$input_dir"` in the `cp` line.